# How to access properties from the function itself or its copies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, properties, copy

What is the best way to access certain properties of a function or its copies from within the function object being called? Example code:

```
"use strict";
var func=function(){
    // need to access certain properties of itself or its future copies:
    alert(*thisFuncObject*.prop); // *thisFuncObject* is the missing reference to the function object being called
};
func.prop=1;

var func2=func.bind({}); // copy func
func2.prop=2; // assign new prop
func2(); // I need it to alert 2
```

`arguments.callee` is not the option, because it seems that it'll be deprecated.

Comment: That's not possible. `.bind` creates a new function which simply calls the original function (`func`). Even if you'd use `arguments.callee`, it would refer to `func`.

Comment: I have a complicated workaround with passing data to the function body using `func.bind({ prop:2 })`, but there must be a more beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've come up to this solution:

```
var original=function(){
    alert((this||original).prop);
};
original.prop=0;
original.clone=function(){
    return function func(){
        return (this||original).apply(func, arguments);
    };
};

var copy=original.clone();
copy.prop=1;

var copy2=original.clone();
copy2.prop=2;

original(); // alerts 0
copy(); // alerts 1
copy2(); // alerts 2
```

Btw, who knows how to add clone() method to its return, in order to make copies of copies using `copy.clone()`? It's not that obvious...

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to access certain properties of a function **or its copies** from within the function object being called?

That's not possible. `.bind` creates a new function which simply calls the original function (`func`). Even if you'd use `arguments.callee`, it would refer to `func`.

---

Disregarding derivates of the original function, you can use a named function expression:

```
var func = function someName(){
    alert(someName.prop);
};
func.prop = 1;
func();
```

`someName` will only be available inside the function itself.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it too much complicated? Maybe just do it this way:

```
var func = function(*thisFuncObject*){
    alert(*thisFuncObject*.prop);
};
func2({ prop: 2});
```

Comment: I my original code I use these functions as factories, so I cannot pass properties this way. Thank you anyway.

Comment: My case is that properties changed dynamically depending on the arguments passed to the function and mustn't be declared explicitly every time.